# Show content based on holidays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

- ruby 1.9.2p290
- rails 3.1.1

I have these models:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :festivity 
end

class Festivity < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :recipes 
end
```

I have the following field in the "recipes" table:

```
festivity_id
```

And the following datetime fields in the "festivities" table:

```
starts_at
ends_at
```

How to display the content based on festivities dates?

I started think in this static way:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def home
  @recipes_by_festivities = Recipe.where(:festivity_id => 4).all(:order => 'RAND()', :limit => 8)
 end
end
```

For example: In Xmas period (about all december month), I want to show a recipe list with the festivity_id = 1. In Thanksgiving period I wanna just a list of recipes with festivity_id = 4.

Am I clear? Let me know if I not.

**SOLUTION**

```
@current_festivity = Festivity.find(:last, :conditions => ["? between starts_at AND ends_at", Time.utc(0,Time.now.month,Time.now.day,0,0,0)])

@recipes_by_festivities = Recipe.where(:festivity_id => @current_festivity).all(:order => 'RAND()', :limit => 8)
```

Comment: @festivity = Festivity(100);@festivity.recipies.where(:order => 'RAND()', :limit => 8) should do. But I did not get what you mean by date ranges. Are you talking about pagination and sorting based on the column like start date or end date

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to understand what you actually want. You want Recipes or Festivities? And wish ones?

Comment: Sorry about my english.

For example: In Xmas, I want to show recipes with the festivity_id = 1. In Thanksgiving I wanna just recipes with festivity_id = 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes `starts_at` and `ends_at` are saved with the same year (0), except if the period is in the middle of two years (Christmas time, for example): in that case, the `ends_at` year must be 1.

```
Festivity.create(name: 'Christmas time', starts_at: Time.utc(0,12,25,0,0,0), ends_at: Time.utc(1,1,6,23,59,59))
Festivity.create(name: 'Ferragosto', starts_at: Time.utc(0,8,15,0,0,0), ends_at: Time.utc(0,8,15,23,59,59))

Recipe.create(festivity: Festivity.find_by_name('Periodo natalizio'))
Recipe.create(festivity: Festivity.find_by_name('Ferragosto'))

# Searching for festivities today
Recipe.includes(:festivity).where(['? BETWEEN festivities.starts_at AND festivities.ends_at', Time.utc(0,Time.now.month,Time.now.day,12,0,0)]).all
# Searching for festivities on 15 August (in Italy there is a festivity that is called Ferragosto)
Recipe.includes(:festivity).where(['? BETWEEN festivities.starts_at AND festivities.ends_at', Time.utc(0,8,15,12,0,0)]).all
# Searching for festivities on 28 December
Recipe.includes(:festivity).where(['? BETWEEN festivities.starts_at AND festivities.ends_at', Time.utc(0,12,28,12,0,0)]).all
```

And this is a possible implementation of a function:

```
def recipes_on(day, month)
  Recipe.includes(:festivity).where(['? BETWEEN festivities.starts_at AND festivities.ends_at', Time.utc(0,month,day,12,0,0)]).all
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this solution right now and give you a feedback.

Comment: remember to vote up my answer if it answers to your question ;)

Comment: I didn't get the right results. The searching for festivities today bring me 3 festivities when the result must be only one. For example: Today (april 25) is in the middle of Mothers Day in Brazil (starts_at: April 9 and ends_at: May 13). But the result shows 2 others more: Carnival (starts_at: 2 January and ends_at: 22 February ) and Easter (starts_at: 23 February and ends_at: 8 April )

Comment: O.O It must work, it's just SQL! :) can you please write the SQL that Rails generates when you run the code?

Comment: There are a performance question too. Is it the best way to do this? The sql generated is so long that doesn't fit here. Here's a resume: SQL (140.4ms) SELECT recipes.id AS t0_r0, recipes.name AS t0_r1, recipes.description AS t0_r2 ...festivities.starts_at AS t1_r4, festivities.ends_at AS t1_r5 ... FROM recipes LEFT OUTER JOIN festivities ON festivities.id = recipes.festivity_id WHERE recipes.status_id = 1 AND ('0000-04-26 12:00:00' BETWEEN festivities.starts_at AND festivities.ends_at) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8

Comment: uhm, I didn't understand why my solution doesn'ìt work to you (it's the same SQL!)... whatever! ;-)

Comment: I'm still using your sql, but it's bring me 3 results which the last is the one I want. For that reason I used Festivity.find(:last). Your SQL is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is create a "name" field in the festivities table, then use the [holidays gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/holidays) to determine if there's a holiday on a specific date.

```
Holdays.on(Date.today)
```

Which will return a list of hashes: each hash has a name key. Then you could use that to look up the correct Festivity object `current_festival = Festivies.where(:name => Holdays.on(Date.today)[0][:name])` and from there get the recipes: `current_festival.recipes`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't know the holidays gem. It seems very interesting! I will try too, but I'm looking for a solution without a gem. But it seems really interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find recipes by festivities, you can do this:

```
def home
  festivity_today = some_custom_festivity_lookup(Time.now)
  if !festivity_today.nil?
    @recipes = Recipe.where(festivity_id: festivity_today.id).limit(8)
  else
    @recipes = Recipe.limit(8)
  end
end
```

Comment: The "festivity_id" must be dynamic based on date of holiday. For example: In Xmas, I want to show recipes with the festivity_id = 1. In Thanksgiving I wanna just recipes with festivity_id = 4.

Comment: The number 10 is just for illustration. You can find out the festivity -id first by probably doing some custom lookup based on today's date and then use it to find recipes. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Salil, thanks for your answer! But in fact what I want is exactly the "some_custom_festivity_lookup". How to do it? I'm new to Ruby/Rails.